# Apache error log is empty, yet php app was interrupted

Tags: apache-2.4, php7

Try to find issue, have a PHP app run under Apache

> Server version: Apache/2.4.10
>
> php module = libphp7.1.so

vhost~nothing special:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myapp.net
    ...
    Loglevel error
    ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog --american /var/log/app.error.log.%Y%m%d"
    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog --american /var/log/app.access.log.%Y%m%d" combined
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

php app on finishing writes logs.

**Now the question**:
in which situation is possible that both Apache my-app.error.log
and php - generated logs are empty?

FS is ok, both logs updated conststantly, only there is a claim about sigle invocation (request).

My concirn is that if PHP-app was interrupted unexpectedly, than it should be 500-error, and should be logged by Apache, please let me know what I'm missing.

---

Disclaimer:

Maybe question is silly, yet it is) I'm bad in Administration, admit, so maybe I misundetstood things, so hope for the ray of light here

Comment: Is php actually [configured to log errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) ?

Comment: @HBruijn, yes, as I wrote FS is ok, both logs updated conststantly. invocations(requests) before and after were logged, only one claimed to be missed. Like if php script had not catched error and was thrown without finishing

Comment: Start by trying to remove cronolog from the equation and let Apache write to files directly. You will then know if the problem is with Apache/PHP or with cronolog/FS